# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut of element's sibling

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I want to make a specific div (the first sibling of a specific  element) fadeIn and eventually fadeOut when mouse over/mouse out of another div.
The div, which schould be fading is position exactly above the other one.
I succesfully design the code for one element using the $(document).ready(), but I want to be more fading elements on the side and I don't to show them all at once, so I had to modify the functions.

Here is the functions code:

```
function clenShow() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
}
function clenHide() {
    $(this).next().fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="clenove" onMouseOver="clenShow()" onMouseOut="clenHide()" href="page1.html" title="">
   <div class="clenovePhoto">
   </div>
   <div class="clenoveText">
      <h2>Head text</h2>
      <p>Content text...</p>
   </div>
</a>
<a class="clenove" onMouseOver="clenShow()" onMouseOut="clenHide()" href="page2.html" title="">
   <div class="clenovePhoto">
   </div>
   <div class="clenoveText">
       <h2>Head text #2</h2>
       <p>Content text #2</p>
   </div>
</a>
```

The element that should fade in and out is the one with the class "clenoveText"
Does anybody know some simple solution?

Comment: Which elements should fade in and out? Also, `.next()` isn't what you want to use here, and avoid inline event handlers.

Comment: which element of the HTML do you want to have the fadein/fadeout?

Comment: The element for fade in and out is the one with the class "clenoveText"

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use a class for the hover element and a relative selector for the sibling:

```
<img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />

$('.hover').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeOut();
}, function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/j3w35pck/)**

Notice that there's no JavaScript in your markup this way, which is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand you but you can use css3 instead of javascript.

Check it here:

```
<a class="clenove" href="page1.html" title="">
   <div class="clenovePhoto">
   </div>
   <div class="clenoveText">
      <h2>Head text</h2>
      <p>Content text...</p>
   </div>
</a>
<a class="clenove" href="page2.html" title="">
   <div class="clenovePhoto">
   </div>
   <div class="clenoveText">
       <h2>Head text #2</h2>
       <p>Content text #2</p>
   </div>
</a>
```

css:

```
.clenove * {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.clenove:hover * {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/vv2knmxa/

Comment: This doesn't show a sibling relationship like is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the elements identifiers to be referenced by jQuery. Then add an init function after the body loads which defines your handlers.

HTML

```
<body onload="init()">
  <a class="clenove" id="page1" href="page1.html" title="">
    <div class="clenovePhoto">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="clenoveText" id="fade1">
      <h2>Head text</h2>
      <p>Content text...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="clenove" id="page2" href="page2.html" title="">
    <div class="clenovePhoto">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="clenoveText" id="fade2">
      <h2>Head text #2</h2>
      <p>Content text #2</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
```

JS

```
function init() {
  $( "#page1" ).hover(function() {
    $( "#fade1" ).fadeIn( "slow" )
    $( "#fade2" ).fadeOut( "slow" )
  });
  $( "#page2" ).hover(function() {
    $( "#fade1" ).fadeOut( "slow" )
    $( "#fade2" ).fadeIn( "slow" )
  });
}
```